1980s? detective film: son (early twenties) of police officer wants to be private investigator
I saw this on German television, dubbed, probably mid to late 1980s. I'm moderately sure it is a North American production, though it might be a made-for-tv movie rather than a Hollywood film, or Canadian. 
The film is set in what was then the present, i.e. mid 1970s to mid 1980s. The protagonist is a young man in his twenties, who wants to be a private investigator. His father is a policeman, still active, I think, probably with an important desk job rather than a patrolman. His father does not want him to become a P.I., but at the end of the film, when the son has mastered his first case, makes his peace with his son's decision.
The son is portrayed as somewhat naive, or at least a romantic. He is shown to be fan of noir films, and I think I remember one scene where he is in front of a movie poster (in his room? at a cinema?) and practices dangling a cigarette from his lips, trying to imitate either Bogart or Jean-Paul Belmondo.
It's in colour, but plays with various noir tropes, none of which I really remember, except there must have been a femme fatale, older than the boy, and rain, and a city as setting.

Close, so close... I just watched a few minutes from an episode of The Rockford Files, which featured a character Richie Brockelman (Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richie_Brockelman,_Private_Eye), who then got his own spin-off series, only a few episodes' worth. Brockelman is 22, a private eye, with disapproving parents. I watched the pilot episode - some scenes struck me as familiar, but the father is no policeman, the son doesn't smoke, it's not particulalry noir, although I read Brockelman is said to be a Bogart fan. (Not much about that in the pilot, though.)
